# Chrome Extension: Automatically download a screenshot taken with 'chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab'

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, screenshot

I'm new to the world of Chrome extensions / auto-downloading. I have a background page which takes a screenshot of the visible webpage with `chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab()`. In my popup I have:

```
chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(null, {}, function (image) {
  // Here I want to automatically download the image
});
```

I've done something similar with a `blob` before but I'm totally at a loss as to how to download an image as well as how to do it automatically.

In practice, I want my Chrome extension to screenshot + download the image automatically whenever a particular page is loaded (I'm guessing this will have to be achieved by having my content script talk to my background page, correct?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, as you said you can use [Message Passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) to get it done. By content scripts to detect the switch on particular pages, then chat with the background page in order to capture screenshot for that page. Your content script should send a message using `chrome.runtime.sendMessage`, and the background page should listen using `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener`:

Sample codes I created and tested it works with me:

**Content script(myscript.js):**

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {

  });
```

**Background.js:**

```
var screenshot = {
  content : document.createElement("canvas"),
  data : '',

  init : function() {
    this.initEvents();
  },
 saveScreenshot : function() {
    var image = new Image();
    image.onload = function() {
      var canvas = screenshot.content;
      canvas.width = image.width;
      canvas.height = image.height;
      var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
      context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

      // save the image
      var link = document.createElement('a');
      link.download = "download.png";
      link.href = screenshot.content.toDataURL();
      link.click();
      screenshot.data = '';
    };
    image.src = screenshot.data; 
  },
initEvents : function() {
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if (request.greeting == "hello") {
          chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(null, {format : "png"}, function(data) {
                screenshot.data = data;
                screenshot.saveScreenshot();

            }); 

        }
    });
  }
};
screenshot.init();
```

Also keep in mind to register your content script's code and permissions in **manifest file:**

```
"permissions": ["<all_urls>","tabs"],
    "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://www.particularpageone.com/*", "http://www.particularpagetwo.com/*"],
      "js": ["myscript.js"]
    }
  ]
```

It captures the screenshot and download the image automatically as .png whenever a particular page is loaded. Cheers!

Comment: i used your code to download auto screenshot of page. but it always show me alert to save the file. i dont want to have an alert and save it to download automatically... i am using mac and chrome browser (both are latest ). any idea please

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative to message passing that should accomplish the same:

In my `manifest.json`

```json
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "permissions": ["activeTab", "scripting"],
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
...
```

In `background.js`

```js
const download = (dataurl, filename) => {
    const link = document.createElement("a");
    link.href = dataurl;
    link.download = filename;
    link.click();
}

chrome.action.onClicked.addListener((tab) => {
    chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(async (dataUrl) => {
        await chrome.scripting.executeScript({
            func: download,
            target: { tabId: tab.id },
            args: [dataUrl, 'test.png'],
        });
    });
});
```